# No. of rows 1 less than expected in a jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

While printing this jagged array I am getting the no of rows to be 1 less than expected. It should start with 0th index to (h-1)th index creating a total of h rows. What am I doing wrong?

h is the no. of rows.

```
        int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[][] arr = new int[h][];

        for(int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = new int[i+1]; 
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();

            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How many rows did you expect and how many rows did it actually print?

Answer (score 2):

That's because your inner for-loop has the condition `j < i`. If `i` is 0 in the first pass, the inner for-loop will not be passed.

Try it with

```cs
for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
{
  Console.Write(arr[i][j] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is it!

Answer (score 2):

The arrays have a growing list of elements, starting with 1 so if you want to scan all the items:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();

    for(int j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, another correct answer, sorry guys I don't seem to be able now to delete my answers without flagging.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
new int[i];
```

Instead of:

```
new int[i+1]
```

Or is it `h - 1`? Just change that index of the array.

Or you need `j < arr[i].Length`